# Conditional ordering with priority to a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with 4 columns:

1. ProductID
2. IsSponsored
3. Rank
4. PopularityScore

I want to get top 20 Products ordered by `Rank` and `PopularityScore`. However `Rank` is considered only if `IsSponsored = 1`.
I have tried using `CASE` in `ORDER BY` clause. Something like:

```
SELECT ProductID
FROM ProductTable 
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN IsSponsored = 1 THEN RANK END ASC,
CASE WHEN IsSponsored = 0 THEN PopularityScore END DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

The Problem I'm facing is, since number of rows with `IsSponsored = 0` >> number of rows with `IsSponsored = 1` and the limit 20, MySQL fetches rows with `IsSponsored = 0` ordered by `PopularityScore`.
What I want is get to all Sponsored Products ordered by Ranks and then supplemented by non sponsored Products ordered by Popularity score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try conditional logic on all three:

```
ORDER BY (IsSponsored = 1) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN IsSponsored = 1 THEN RANK END) ASC,
         PopularityScore DESC;
```

The first key is an expression on a boolean:  this evaluates to true (1) or false (0).  I removed the `CASE` from the third key because it is redundant -- you can put it back if you like.